# Counterpart for <frame> that supports tranparency in chromium browser?

Tags: php, html, firefox, chromium

I have a website and in one of the pages is a photo album, which appears thus in Chromium:

[image: Appearance in Chromium]

and in firefox, as below:

[image: Appearance in Firefox]

As you can see, there is a white patch to the left and above the gallery box in the former picture while in the latter there is tranparency throughout the outside of the box. I want to get rid of these white patches. I learnt that it necessarily boils down to how Chromium handles iframes. I figured out that this is the code fragment that needs change so that the transparency is achieved in both browsers.

```
echo "<frameset rows='424px' frameborder=0 >";
echo "<frame name='akc' style='background-color: transparent' noresize='noresize'";
echo "src='aneesh.php?album=" . start() . "'/></frameset>";
```

So my question boils down to getting a replacement code that produces the same result in Chromium as in Firefox. I want a complete replacement for frame tag. (A tag that can be targeted just like frames, which can contain webpages - like frame where we use 'src' attribute - and also support transparency)

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use frames? They are deprecated and pretty much nobody uses them anymore...

Comment: Sadly I could not, thus far, achieve what I have mentioned in the question, circumventing frames!

Comment: to be absolutely clear: if you're using frames, then you're doing something wrong. There is no use case for them at all. If you *really* need to have your page split into separate documents, then use `iframe` instead, but I'd avoid that too if possible for this kind of usage.

Comment: Thanks very much. Really sad iframe eluded my mind! Indeed my problem has at least temporarily been solved by iframe. Thanks!

Comment: @ Spudley you can turn the iframe comment to an answer, I'll accept it .

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `<div>` then use `<?php include('aneesh.php?album=whatever'); ?>` to include a PHP script within the div.

If you wanted to change the contents of the `<div>` on the fly, you could use [jQuery's AJAX functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to request the output of the `album.php` script then write them to the `<div>` by ID, something like *(note: untested, but it's along the right lines)*:

```
<script>
$((){
    var album = start();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "aneesh.php",
        data: { 'album': album }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $('#album').html = msg;
    });
});
</script>

...

<div id='album'></div>
```

Frames [are obsolete](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features), haven't been in common use since the 90s and [pose massive issues to people using non-standard browsing methods](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/website-frames/). Don't use them.

Comment: So here the line

    $('#album').html = msg;

eventually changes the value of 'album'

Comment: It said Internal Server Error. When I click on an album title, the album photos appear in another tab!

Comment: @AneeshKarthikC - Yes, this is called a jQuery selector. It will select the element with `id=album` and replace its inner HTML with `msg` (the response to the `AJAX` request).

Comment: So is msg determined by the AJAX request here?

Comment: Yes, AJAX will open the PHP file then read the reply (which should be HTML), then insert the reply to the div.

Comment: Right, I still face Internal Server Problem, as also, still the albums open in new tab :-(